# Fraud of HMRC check?

Tags: united-kingdom, check, fraud

I have quick question. I have been informed by HMRC that I overpaid income tax. However, I never received any check in post. It turns out it happened not long after I moved form, one address to another two years ago. Is there any possibility someone else that moved in could cash this check? I requested check to be reissued however lady dealing with enquiry couldn’t confirm or deny if 1st check was cashed. I am bit in a limbo as we are talking about good few hundreds.

Comment: "Is there any possibility someone else that moved in could cash this check?"  Sure, by scribbling something and saying it's your signature.

Comment: I see and, in that case, I suppose I need to report it as fraud. However, since it has been two years is there any point?

Comment: `I have been informed by HMRC that I overpaid income tax`  Email or letter ? **Email -> FRAUD**. Cheques are A/C payee, if sent. Or will be adjusted in your next tax year tax code. Call up HMRC to confirm.

Comment: @RonJohn You can’t cash a cheque made out to someone else simply by signing it in the UK, the way you can in the US, so I think the chances of that are low.

Comment: Wintermute, do you have any updates? Today I found out I am in your same situation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you get a P800 letter explaining the amount overpaid and the process to get the refund issued. If not this could be a scam. Read https://www.gov.uk/government/news/hmrc-warns-on-tax-refund-scams

If you have completed the process and didn't get a check or went to incorrect address after you moved... It's is a very low possibility of new resident encashing fraudulently... Generally people would be honest and would ignore the check or return to HMRC.

The remote possibility of of the place being rented by a fraudster he would have to either tamper with the name or endorse with your fake signature...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn’t get P800 but expected tax return as only worked during summer and paid tax as “full time” employ. Never attended to my taxes as always delayed by something. Now I chased it with HMRC and they gave me dates and amount on the check. Bit worried as it has been a while and now proving fraud could prove tricky not to mention if anyone would chase it after 2 years.

Comment: @Wintermute If you have confirmation from HMRC on check issued, it may have gone uncashed. Good luck with chasing HMRC.

Comment: Generally, UK Government agencies are happy to reissue a lost or unreceived cheque but they will want to confirm that it was not cashed. Getting this confirmation is not instant; often banking services are outsourced and it can take a few days to get confirmation, and cancel the cheque (so it will bounce if anyone tries to pay it into an account).